# Rerender components in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have nested components. I have a button and SVG component as instructed by [this tutorial](https://github.com/ForceDotComLabs/sldsx/blob/master/tutorial/tutorial.md#module-2-decompose-the-app-into-components)

How can I update the icon? Can i call the rerender function in the controller of the component?

```
<c:button class="slds-button" 
svgXlinkHref="/resource/slds080/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#chevronright" 
svgClass="slds-icon slds-icon-text-default"
data="{!opp.Id}" 
onclick="{!c.showTask}"
/>
```

Specifically, I want to update the `svgXlinkHref`. I tried `cmp.set()` on click but it won't work.

Comment: Can you paste your js controller action for showTask ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest example with updating view value from js controller:

View:

```
<aura:component controller="MyController">
    <aura:attribute name="href" type="String" default="Hello World"/>
        <ui:button label="{!v.href}" press="{!c.Update}" />
</aura:component>
```

then set `href` value in controller:

```
({
    Update : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.href', 'Hello Lightning!');
    },
})
```

Try to adapt it to your scenario and it should do the trick.

Comment: error occurs Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined on svg component

Comment: I updated my answer to be just a working example that I tested in my own org. Try to adapt it to your scenario. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what I did was completely refresh the component by destroying the original and making a new one. Note, this uses the standard SVG component as described in the docs.

Markup:

```
<a aura:id="iconbutton" onclick="{!c.changeIcon}" href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-button slds-button--icon-container">
  <c:SVG aura:id="icon" class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--small slds-m-top--small" xlinkHref="{!$Resource.SLDS105 + '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#chevronright'}"/>
</a>
```

JS

```
changeIcon : function(component) {

    var item = component.find('icon');
    item.destroy();

    $A.createComponent(
        "c:SVG",
        {
            "aura:id": "icon",
            "class"  : "slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--small slds-m-top--small",
            "xlinkHref" : component.get('v.chevronLeft')
        },
        function(newSVG){
            //Add the new button to the body array
            if (component.isValid()) {
                var bttn = component.find("iconbutton");
                var body = bttn.get("v.body");
                body.push(newSVG);
                bttn.set("v.iconbutton", body);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

You would probably call `$A.createComponent("c:button....`
For the handler on the button, follow the instructions [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm)

Comment: While this works, it isn't normal to need to destroy a component to re-render it. I'm using an svg component where the content is loaded into the view from an XHR (for IE support) - setting the attribute as Bart's answer describes causes the markup to be rendered.

Comment: Did you try it using Chrome, on a Mac? I tried that too first, and it didn't work for me - hence what I did.